# Faster persist and flush for doctrine mongodb odm import

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm, import-from-csv

I am using symfony2 and doctrine mongodb odm to import product data from CSV files. I created a console command to create the `Product` objects and then persist them and flush the `DocumentManager`. The flush is taking upwards of 30 seconds and I only have a couple thousand products. There will potentially be many more in the future.

I am wondering if there are any optimizations/best practices to make flushing a large quantity of new objects faster in doctrine. It seems like there wouldn't need to be that much processing on the objects since they are all new and just need to be added to the collection.

Comment: Are you flushing the _couple thousand_ products at one shot or after each persist?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the flush operation, not the processing before it? Did you benchmark it?

Comment: I did, the parsing of CSV, creating of objects, and persisting all takes 1-2 seconds. the flush call at the end takes 30+ seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could enable Doctrine's logging and profiling. Be sure to do the same for MongoDB. I don't think the problem is PHP processing...

Comment: sorry, i'm an idiot. had xdebug profiler on. still taking 7 seconds to flush with it off, but i suppose that's more reasonable?

Comment: Yes, 7 seconds is reasonable to save more than 2.000 records from a fixture.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem (loading thousands of products from a csv as it would be).  My problem revolved more around running out of memory, but the solution showed a significant increase in speed as well.

Essentially, I put a counter inside the loop and flushed the manager then cleared it every so often.  I found that 150 batch size yielded the best results.  I am sure it depended largely on how you are processing it as I had LOTS of number crunching going on to clean the data before inserting it.

For reference, it loads about 5,500 products with 100+ fields and does processing on them in about 20 seconds.  It was taking 3+ minutes before the modification (if it even finished at all due to running out of memory.)

```
//LOOP  {
   if ($count % $batchSize == 0) {
      $manager->flush();
      $manager->clear();
      gc_collect_cycles();
      if ($count % $batchSize == 0)
         echo $count . ' | ' . number_format((memory_get_usage() / 1024), 4) . " KBs\n";
   }
$count++;
}
```

Don't forget to run the $manager->flush() at least one more time once the loop is complete to catch those 1-149 records that wouldn't trigger it in the loop.

Comment: +1 for the final tip of flush after the loop. I've wasted 2 hours trying to fix a test that wasn't getting a updated result because that ;)

Answer (score -1):

I have a very large database. I find it much more efficient to do a flush every time you insert the code better manages access to the database.

```
$dm->persist($object);
$dm->flush();
$dm->clear();
```

Comment: Doing this would likely result in increased overhead and make the speed problem worse as the full UOW calculations would need to run after each record.